# How do I set up my Java chatroom program to work with port forwarding?

Tags: java, networking, chatroom

I watched a tutorial on simple Java networking, and the tutorial showed the server and client application running on the same computer and it worked, I was wondering if there's a way to make it work on different computers in different homes using port forwarding or something else; Here is my code:

Server.java:

```
package com.cloud.server;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * The Server class extends JFrame and contains all of the code pertaining to the GUI and the server
 * 
 * @author mcjcloud
 *
 */

public class Server extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField userInput;
    private JTextArea convo;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private ServerSocket server;        // establishes server
    private Socket connection;          // establishes connection with other computer

    /**
     * Constructor (basically just sets up the GUI and actionListener(s)
     */
    public Server()
    {
        super("Cloud Messenger");

        userInput = new JTextField();
        userInput.setEditable(false);
        userInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                sendMessage(e.getActionCommand());
                userInput.setText("");
            }
        });
        add(userInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // set up convo (JTextArea)
        convo = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(convo));
        setSize(500, 700);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * startServer() method waits for connection, sets up connection and manages chat
     */
    public void startServer()
    {
        try
        {
            server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0")); // (port number, backlog) backlog (aka qlength) = "how many people can connect at a time"
            while(true) // infinite loop
            {
                try
                {
                    waitForConnection();    // first set up the connection
                    setupStreams();         // set up the streams
                    chat();                 // enable the chat and things
                }
                catch(EOFException eofe)    // EOF = EndOfStream (meaning the input/output stream ended)
                {
                    showMessage("Connection terminated.");
                }
                finally
                {
                    cleanUpConnection();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * waitForConnection() method will wait for the connection, then display connection info
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void waitForConnection() throws IOException
    {
        showMessage("Waiting for connection...");
        connection = server.accept();       // listens for a connection
        showMessage("Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }

    /**
     * setupStream() method gets a stream to send/recieve data
     */
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException
    {
        // setup output stream
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());  // create pathway to allow us to connect to the computer the socket is connected to
        output.flush();

        // setup input stream
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // create pathway to receive messages
        showMessage("Stream setup success.");
    }

    /**
     * chat() method code runs during conversation
     */
    private void chat() throws IOException
    {
        String message = "Chatting enabled";
        showMessage(message);
        setCanType(true);
        do
        {
            try
            {
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage(message);
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
            {
                showMessage("Message recieve failed (Other person's problem)");
            }
        }
        while(!message.equals("CLIENT - /terminate"));
    }

    /**
     * cleanUpConnection() method cleans up the stream and things after the chat has ended
     */
    private void cleanUpConnection()
    {
        showMessage("Closing connection...");
        setCanType(false);
        try
        {
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * sendMessage(String) method sends whatever message you type
     * 
     * @param message is what is going to be shown
     */
    private void sendMessage(String message)
    {
        try
        {
            output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message);  // write the message to the outputstream
            output.flush();
            showMessage("SERVER - " + message);
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            convo.append("ERROR: Message can't be sent.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * showMessage(String)shows whatever needs to be shown on the JTextArea
     */
    private void showMessage(String message)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                convo.append(" " + message + "\n");
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * setCanType() method decides whether or not a user can type
     * 
     * @param canType
     */
    private void setCanType(boolean canType)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                userInput.setEditable(canType);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

InvokeServer.java:

```
package com.cloud.server;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class InvokeServer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        server.startServer();
    }

}
```

Client.java:

```
package com.cloud.client;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Client class is the sister of the Server class in the server application, contains all the code to build GUI and send info to server and receive
 * 
 * @author mcjcloud
 *
 */
public class Client extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField userInput;
    private JTextArea convo;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private String message = "";
    private String serverIP;        // connecting to a specific server
    private Socket connection;

    public Client(String host)
    {
        super("Cloud Messenger");
        serverIP = host;

        userInput = new JTextField();
        userInput.setEditable(false);
        userInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                sendMessage(e.getActionCommand());
                userInput.setText("");
            }
        });
        add(userInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        convo = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(convo));
        setSize(500, 700);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * startClient() method invokes the whole conversation 
     */
    public void startClient()
    {
        try
        {
            boolean connected = false;
            showMessage("Connecting to server...");
            while(!connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    connected = connectToServer();
                }
                catch(ConnectException ce)
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
            setupStreams();
            chat();
        }
        catch(EOFException eofe)
        {
            sendMessage("Connection terminated.");
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            cleanUpConnection();
        }
    }

    /**
     * connectToServer() establishes connection with the server application
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private boolean connectToServer() throws IOException
    {
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);
        showMessage("Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * setupStream() method gets a stream to send/recieve data
     */
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException
    {
        // setup output stream
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());  // create pathway to allow us to connect to the computer the socket is connected to
        output.flush();

        // setup input stream
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // create pathway to receive messages
        showMessage("Stream setup success.");
    }

    /**
     * chat() method code runs during conversation
     */
    private void chat() throws IOException
    {
        String message = "Chatting enabled";
        showMessage(message);
        setCanType(true);
        do
        {
            try
            {
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage(message);
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
            {
                showMessage("Message recieve failed (Other person's problem)");
            }
        }
        while(!message.equals("SERVER - /terminate"));
    }

    /**
     * cleanUpConnection() method cleans up the stream and things after the chat has ended
     */
    private void cleanUpConnection()
    {
        showMessage("Closing connection...");
        setCanType(false);
        try
        {
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * sendMessage(String) method sends whatever message you type
     * 
     * @param message is what is going to be shown
     */
    private void sendMessage(String message)
    {
        try
        {
            output.writeObject("CLIENT - " + message);  // write the message to the outputstream
            output.flush();
            showMessage("CLIENT - " + message);
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            convo.append("ERROR: Message can't be sent.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * showMessage(String) shows whatever needs to be shown on the JTextArea
     */
    private void showMessage(String message)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()   // USE THIS RUNNABLE TO UPDATE GUI
        {
            public void run()
            {
                convo.append(" " + message + "\n");
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * setCanType() method decides whether or not a user can type
     * 
     * @param canType
     */
    private void setCanType(boolean canType)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                userInput.setEditable(canType);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

InvokeClient.java:

```
package com.cloud.client;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class InvokeClient 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Client client = new Client("99.25.233.116");
        client.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.startClient();
    }

}
```

Note:
I tried setting up port forwarding on my home network with the port 6789 to one of my laptops, and that's the laptop I run the server application on.

Comment: Do you have necessary networking between your computer to interact or public IP for server?

Comment: Does the "servermachine" have Firewall settings that block that port? If you start a client on the same machine, can you reach the server? On the same (local) network, can you reach the server from different machine?

Comment: I set up port forwarding on the laptop that runs the server app, and I'm using the public IP address of that computer to connect, I don't have a dedicated server though, the only kind of server I have is an HFS which I don't think will work

Comment: Okay the windows firewall is disabled, but it still won't work on separate computers

Comment: It doesn't work on the same computer.

Comment: UPDATE: If i use the private ipv4 address it does work across computers (on my home network (obviously))

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just undid and redid the port forwarding again and it worked with the public IP address. Thank you all for your help